# Maximum length for string ActorId

Tags: c#, azure, actor, azure-service-fabric

What is the maximum length for a string-based ActorId? And if there is a difference between the maximum possible length and the maximum recommended length, what is the difference and why?

Comment: Is there any “maximum recommended length”?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActorId, per se, does not have a specified limit on length of string-based id. However, while choosing a length for string-based ActorId, you should keep following points in consideration:

1) The ActorStateProvider (implementation of [IActorStateProvider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.servicefabric.actors.runtime.iactorstateprovider.aspx)) stores named-state(s) and reminder(s) for actor. Depending on the implementation, it may have a specific limit on length of string-based ActorId as internally it will be using a combination ActorId, actor state-name and reminder-name (and possibly some internal metadata tags) to uniquely identify persisted named-state(s) and reminder(s) for a given actor.

2) The default ActorStateProvider for actors is [KvsActorStateProvider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.servicefabric.actors.runtime.kvsactorstateprovider.aspx). It is implemented on top a key-value store. It has a key length limit of 872 characters. I would recommend leaving 50 characters for internal metadata tagging and you can use remaining characters to distribute between your string-based ActorId(s) and actor state-names/reminder-names based on you naming schemes.